# React Ant deisgn 4 Table search input cursor going to center

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Im using my react project for ant design 4 table, when I search the table data ,  input cursor going to center and data not searching any solution for this, please look ta my following link and just copy paste address then search you can see the conflict.

**[stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bfnhj8-m46dmx?file=index.js)**

**code here**

```
const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    searchedColumn: '',
  };

  getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : '',
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: text =>
      this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ''}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex,
    });
  };

  handleReset = clearFilters => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: '' });
  };

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('name'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
        width: '20%',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('age'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        key: 'address',
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps('address'),
      },
    ];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that. It works perfectly fine for me. Can you describe the steps you're doing, so I could follow them one by one?

Comment: @Terminat hello there, can you  ( need to copy paste data )search using following `London No. 2 Lake Park` throug the  address col, cursor going to input  center, not a same time should try to several time.

Comment: @core114 Like Terminat pointed out, works absolutely fine. Tried a few times on different resolutions as well.

Comment: @zhulien Thanks, I will try again

Comment: is the problem solved?

Comment: @NishargShah When I copy and paste data name some time   came to .issue  but I type the data name its working fine